# Import pictures in LightRoom via script

Tags: xcode, cocoa, image, lightroom

I am writing an app that copies some pictures somewhere, and would then like to "tell" Lightroom to import automatically these pictures upon next startup, or life if LR is running.
Can I do this via a script ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Create an Automator Task which is run on a change in the given folder. Record a macro to synchronize your base folder.